# Programmatically detecting whether a point is on a circular arc?

Tags: java, android, math, android-canvas, geometry

I have created an arc. I want to do certain things on different arcs when an arc is clicked. How do I know if an arc is touched or not? Can someone please provide some code for onTouch method to do such a calculation. Also please explain it a little bit.

```
package com.example.android.customviews;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.graphics.RectF;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

    /**
     * Limit Indicator is used to show any kind of limits such as Balance and Actual
     * Amount of wallet present in an account. In order to use this in the XML
     * Layout, please include the following: <br />
     * <br />
     * 
     * xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.customviews"
     * 
     * <br /> <br />
     * 
     * Following custom attributes are provided: <br />
     * <br />
     * 
     * custom:borderColor <br />
     * custom:borderRadius <br />
     * custom:outerCircleRadius <br />
     * custom:text <br />
     * custom:textSize <br />
     * custom:innerCircleColor <br />
     * 
     * @author Syed Ahmed Hussain
     */
    public class LimitIndicator extends ViewGroup {

        // ============================================================================================
        // Variables Declaration


        private int     mInnerCircleColor;
        private int     mBorderColor;
        private int     mTextColor;
        private float   mTextSize;
        private String  mTitleText = "";

        private float mHalfOfBorderWidth = 0.0f;
        private float mOuterCircleRadius = 2.0f;
        private float mBorderWidth  = 30.0f;

        private Paint mDialPaint, mTextPaint, mBorderPaint, mInnerCirclePaint;

        private float mCenterX = 100.0f;
        private float mCenterY = 100.0f;

        private int mTotalProgressInDegrees;
        private int mTotalProgress  = -1;

        // Start Angle should be 90 degrees to create a clockwise illusion.
        private int mStartAngle = 270;

        // This should be the one which provides us a percentage wise drawing
        private int mSweepAngle = 1;

        private RectF mBorderBounds = null;

        // ============================================================================================
        // Constructors

        public LimitIndicator(Context pContext) {
            super(pContext);
            Log.d("LimitIndicator", "LimitIndicator(Context pContext) called");
            initialize();
        }

        public LimitIndicator(Context pContext, AttributeSet pAttrs) {
            super(pContext, pAttrs);
            Log.d("LimitIndicator", "LimitIndicator(Context pContext, AttributeSet pAttrs) called");
            TypedArray typedArray = pContext.obtainStyledAttributes(pAttrs, R.styleable.LimitIndicator, 0, 0);

            try {
                mOuterCircleRadius  = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.LimitIndicator_outerCircleRadius, mOuterCircleRadius);
                mTextColor          = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.LimitIndicator_textColor, Color.WHITE);
                mTitleText          = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.LimitIndicator_text);
                mTextSize           = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.LimitIndicator_textSize, 25);
                mTotalProgress      = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.LimitIndicator_numerator, mTotalProgress);
                mBorderColor        = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.LimitIndicator_borderColor, Color.BLACK);
                mBorderWidth        = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.LimitIndicator_borderRadius, mBorderWidth);
                mInnerCircleColor   = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.LimitIndicator_innerCircleColor, Color.GREEN);
            } finally {
                typedArray.recycle();
            }
            initialize();
        }

        // ============================================================================================
        // Initialization

        /**
         * Initialize all elements
         */
        private void initialize() {

            // Set up the paint for the dial
            mDialPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mDialPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mDialPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

             // Set up the paint for the label text
            mTextPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
            mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            mTextPaint.setColor(mTextColor);
            mTextPaint.setTextSize(mTextSize);

            // Set up the paint for the border
            mBorderPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);
            mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
            mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mBorderPaint.setDither(true);

            mInnerCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mInnerCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mInnerCirclePaint.setColor(mInnerCircleColor);

            // mBorderPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            // mBorderPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

            mBorderBounds = new RectF(getLeft(), getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
        }

        // ============================================================================================
        // Drawing on surface

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas pCanvas) {
            super.onDraw(pCanvas);
            Log.d("LimitIndicator", "OnDraw called");

            Log.d("Measured Spec Width", mCenterX + "");
            Log.d("Measured Spec Height", mCenterY + "");

            pCanvas.drawCircle(mCenterX, mCenterY, mOuterCircleRadius, mDialPaint);
            pCanvas.drawCircle(mCenterX, mCenterY, (float) (mOuterCircleRadius - mBorderWidth + 1) , mInnerCirclePaint);
            pCanvas.drawText(mTitleText, mCenterX, mCenterY + 5, mTextPaint);

            pCanvas.drawArc(mBorderBounds, mStartAngle, mSweepAngle, false, mBorderPaint);

            if (mSweepAngle < mTotalProgressInDegrees) {
                mSweepAngle+=3;
                mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth++);
                invalidate();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean pChanged, int pLeft, int pTop, int pRight, int pBottom) {
            Log.d("LimitIndicator", "OnLayout called");
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                getChildAt(i).layout(0, 0, pRight, pBottom);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int pW, int pH, int pOldw, int pOldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(pW, pH, pOldw, pOldh);
            Log.d("LimitIndicator", "OnSizeChanged called");

            float xPad = (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
            float yPad = (getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());

            // To draw Circle in the middle
            mCenterX    = (float) ((pW - xPad) * 0.5);
            mCenterY    = (float) ((pH - yPad) * 0.5);


            //  This (mBorderBounds.bottom needs to be fixed. Width &
            // Height should be equal in order
            // to create a perfect circle. Otherwise an
            // Oval will be created! :P 

            // Bounds for creating an arc
            mHalfOfBorderWidth = (float) (mBorderWidth * 0.5);
            mBorderBounds.right     = mCenterX + mOuterCircleRadius - mHalfOfBorderWidth; 
            mBorderBounds.left      = mCenterX - mOuterCircleRadius + mHalfOfBorderWidth;
            mBorderBounds.top       = mCenterY - mOuterCircleRadius + mHalfOfBorderWidth;
            mBorderBounds.bottom    = mCenterY + mOuterCircleRadius - mHalfOfBorderWidth;

        }

        // =========================================================================================================

        /**
         * Start the progress/animation. Use this method to start the animated view.
         */
        public void startProgress() {
            if (mTotalProgress >= 0) {
                float progressInDegrees = mTotalProgress;
                mTotalProgressInDegrees = (int) (progressInDegrees/100 * 360);
                invalidate();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent pEvent) {

            return super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(pEvent);
        }


        // =========================================================================================================

        // Getters && Setters!

        /**
         * @return the dialRadius
         */
        public float getDialRadius() {
            return mOuterCircleRadius;
        }

        /**
         * @param pDialRadius
         *            the dialRadius to set
         */
        public void setDialRadius(float pDialRadius) {
            mOuterCircleRadius = pDialRadius;
        }


        /**
         * @return the textSize
         */
        public float getTextSize() {
            return mTextSize;
        }

        /**
         * @param pTextSize the textSize to set
         */
        public void setTextSize(float pTextSize) {
            mTextSize = pTextSize;
        }

        /**
         * @return the textColor
         */
        public int getTextColor() {
            return mTextColor;
        }

        /**
         * @param pTextColor the textColor to set
         */
        public void setTextColor(int pTextColor) {
            mTextColor = pTextColor;
        }

        /**
         * @return the borderColor
         */
        public int getBorderColor() {
            return mBorderColor;
        }

        /**
         * @param pBorderColor the borderColor to set
         */
        public void setBorderColor(int pBorderColor) {
            mBorderColor = pBorderColor;
        }

        /**
         * @return the innerCircleColor
         */
        public int getInnerCircleColor() {
            return mInnerCircleColor;
        }

        /**
         * @param pInnerCircleColor the innerCircleColor to set
         */
        public void setInnerCircleColor(int pInnerCircleColor) {
            mInnerCircleColor = pInnerCircleColor;
        }

        /**
         * @return the titleText
         */
        public String getTitleText() {
            return mTitleText;
        }

        /**
         * @param pTitleText the titleText to set
         */
        public void setTitleText(String pTitleText) {
            mTitleText = pTitleText;
        }

        /**
         * @return the outerCircleRadius
         */
        public float getOuterCircleRadius() {
            return mOuterCircleRadius;
        }

        /**
         * @param pOuterCircleRadius the outerCircleRadius to set
         */
        public void setOuterCircleRadius(float pOuterCircleRadius) {
            mOuterCircleRadius = pOuterCircleRadius;
        }

        /**
         * @return the borderWidth
         */
        public float getBorderWidth() {
            return mBorderWidth;
        }

        /**
         * @param pBorderWidth the borderWidth to set
         */
        public void setBorderWidth(float pBorderWidth) {
            mBorderWidth = pBorderWidth;
        }

        /**
         * @return the totalProgress
         */
        public int getTotalProgress() {
            return mTotalProgress;
        }

        /**
         * @param pTotalProgress the totalProgress to set
         */
        public void setTotalProgress(int pTotalProgress) {
            mTotalProgress = pTotalProgress;
        }

    }
```

EDIT

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent pEvent) {

        double x = pEvent.getX();
        double y = pEvent.getY();

        double x1 = x - mCenterX;
        double y1 = y - mCenterY;

        double distance = Math.sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1);

        RectF topBoundingRect = new RectF(mCenterX - mOuterCircleRadius, mCenterY - mOuterCircleRadius, mCenterX + mOuterCircleRadius, mCenterY);

        if (Math.abs(distance - mOuterCircleRadius) <= MAX_TOUCH_TOLERANCE && topBoundingRect.contains((float) x, (float) y)) {
            // the user is touching the arc. Which arc is tapped? How do I know that?

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I won't post code for this, since I'm not completely comfortable working with Java UIs, but the math behind what you're describing shouldn't be too hard.

To make sure that I understand what you're doing: you have a circular arc defined by some center point (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>), a radius r, a start angle θ<sub>0</sub>, and an end angle θ<sub>1</sub>. You then want to take a test point (x, y) and determine whether the user clicked on the circle.

This problem is a lot easier to solve if we translate everything back to the origin, since trigonometry is always easier relative to the origin. So let's let

> x' = x - x<sub>0</sub>
>
> y' = y - y<sub>0</sub>

Now that you have x' and y', we can determine how far away it is from the center of the circle by computing

> dist = √(x'<sup>2</sup> + y'<sup>2</sup>)

If this value isn't close to the radius r, then there's no way that the point clicked is anywhere near the arc. Since the arc mathematically is infinitely small, you probably want to set up some "tolerance" for when the user clicks on the arc. You could, for example, define some constant `TOLERANCE` and then assume the user is clicking on the circumference of the circle if

> |dist - r| ≤ TOLERANCE

Now, this assumes that the arc is just the border of the circle. If you are drawing a filled-in circular arc, you can instead just check whether

> dist ≤ r + TOLERANCE

This checks whether the point is inside the circle at all.

Now, at this point you can check whether the point is in/inside the circle at all. The next question is whether they clicked on a part of the circle that's part of the arc. To do this, you can compute the angle θ at which the the point is relative to the center of the circle by using `Math.atan2` and computing `Math.atan2(y', x')`. This gives you back an angle θ (*in radians*). You can then check whether θ<sub>0</sub> ≤ θ ≤ θ<sub>1</sub>, which will then tell you if they clicked on the part of the circle you care about.

In short:

- Compute x' and y' from x, y, x<sub>0</sub>, and y<sub>0</sub>.
- Compute dist from x' and y'.
- Determine whether they hit the circle / circumference by using the above math.
- Use `Math.atan2` to get the angle θ
- See if θ is in the range you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for such an explanation. I like it. Just few questions though. What is a test point X and Y? A tap on a screen perhaps? 

|dist - r| is a mode and that the value can never be in negative?



You might want to write the code in other language or Suedo code it cause its gonna make my life a little easier.

Comment: And what if you have multiple arcs? then what?

Comment: @Ahmed- X and Y are the point that's clicked on the screen, yes. If you have multiple arcs, you can just repeat this process for each. Also, I believe what I have written is pretty close to the code you'd need; I don't think adding pseudocode would clarify very much.

Comment: @templateypedef - Thanks :) ... If you take a look I have added some code for the calculation under the Edit. Can you take a look and tell me if thats the right way of doing it?

Comment: @Ahmed- You're not computing the angle that the click makes with the center of the circle. That will help tell you where you are in the circle, from which it should be easy to determine which arc you clicked.

Comment: @Ahmed- I've given you the mathematical derivations of all the code you need to write. I even gave you the names of specific methods to call. You have all the information you need, and I think it's inappropriate for you to ask me to translate all of this math into code for you.

Comment: And I thank you for that. Problem that I am running into (as you can see in the edited section) is that I don't know which arc it has been touched. If you look closer to the code I have provided you'll see that your assumption is that each circle is drawn in a view which is not the case. This is a View Group in which I have drawn all of these things in one place. Therefore that means If I have to detect the bounds of a touched arc and also where the point is when the user hits it.

Comment: According to what I have understood from what you have provided. I have to first calculate the bounds of each arc and then do if/else conditions to see which arc has been touched. So my problem is which arc has the user touched. I hope this clears the air

Comment: @Ahmed- Can't you just iterate over all the arcs and test each to see if it was hit?

Comment: No. You haven't looked at the code at all. I cannot iterate through the loop cause there is no array that keeps the track of how many arcs or circles you have. It is supposed to be a viewgroup drawing all the things at once and then draw and invalidate to do animation.